Libsodium installation and configuration error
when i run my project iam getting this error
my libsodium is present inside
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.20/lib. this pacakge
Jun 26, 2024 10:18:06 AM jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeRuntime buildNativeTypeAliases
SEVERE: failed to load type aliases: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.platform.unknown.darwin.TypeAliases

dlopen(libsodium.dylib, 0x0009): tried: 'libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/aawasthi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-21.0.3/Contents/Home/bin/./libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/aawasthi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-21.0.3/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libsodium.dylib, 0x0009): tried: 'libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/aawasthi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-21.0.3/Contents/Home/bin/./libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/aawasthi/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-21.0.3/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libsodium.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsodium.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.loadNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:87)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:70)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.findSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:59)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:117)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:59)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:43)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:290)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:269)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.NaCl$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NaCl.java:51)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.NaCl.sodium(NaCl.java:29)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.crypto.SecretBox.encrypt(SecretBox.java:47)
    at com.newrelic.beyondapi.sodium.SodiumSimpleBox.encrypt(SodiumSimpleBox.java:25)
    at com.newrelic.beyondapi.sodium.SodiumSimpleBoxIT.correctly encrypt a value(SodiumSimpleBoxIT.groovy:15)


iam not able to understand about this error
if someone  have idea please share your inputs it would be great help to me
iam using springoot java
and OS iam using is macOS
iam trying to run the groovy test case of SecretBox encrption of libsodium libraray
but it looks like it is not properly setup
what should i try next
